# What is wrong with my calculation for variance?

Tags: statistics, brownian-motion

I don't get this, I am asked if the following $X_t$ is a brownian motion or not.

> $Z$ is a standard normal variate. $X_t=\sqrt{t}Z$. I s$X_t$ a Brownian motion?

Answer is apparently no and one of the reasons is that the variance of $X_t-X_s=$ is $(\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{s})^2$. But I get $t-s$ as the variance of the increment.
Here's how

> $var(X_t-X_s)=\mathbb{E}[(X_t-X_s)^2]-\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_s]^2$ say $0<s<t$.
>
> Then,
>   $\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-2X_tX_s+X_s^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X_t]-\mathbb{E}[X_2])^2 = \mathbb{E}[x_t^2]-2\mathbb{E}[X_tX_s]+\mathbb{E}[x_s^2]-(0)^2$ since $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=\sqrt{t}\mathbb{E}[Z]$ and $Z$ is a standard normal variable. Same for $X_s$.
>
> So $\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=t \mathbb{E}[Z^2]$. $Z$ is standard normal so $var(Z)=\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=1$. I calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_tX_s]$ using that $X_s-X_0$ and $X_t-X_s$ are independent. Then $\mathbb{E}[X_s]\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_s]+\mathbb{E}[X_s^2]=s$ is what I get and substituting back, my overall variance is $t-2s+s=t-s$

So yes, the variance is $t-s$ and not  $(\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{s})^2$. What did I do wrong? I cannot find a fault in my argument. Please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: $E[X_t]=\sqrt{t}E[Z]\neq \sqrt{s}E[Z]=E[X_s]$.

Comment: @John Trail Can I ask what book are you using?

Comment: it's a note from lecturers so probably something not available in public but it's apparently loosely based on Bjork's *Arbitrage theory in continuous time *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the *sample path* or *realization* of the process $\{X_t\colon t \geq 0\}$ corresponding to the outcome $Z = z$. It is the *curve* $\sqrt{t}z\mathbf 1_{[0,\infty)}(t)$ passing through the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,z)$. Does this resemble Brownian motion at all?

More specifically and in response to your question as to where you went wrong in your calculations, let us look at your claim that

> for $t > s >0$, $\ldots$ $X_s-X_0$ and $X_t-X_s$ are independent

Since $X_0 = 0$, we have that $X_s-X_0 = X_s = \sqrt{s}Z$ while
$X_t-X_s = \sqrt{t}Z-\sqrt{s}Z = \left(\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{s}\right)Z$
*both* are multiples of $Z$ and so cannot be independent. Indeed,
since $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, it is straightforward
to get that the variance of 
$X_t-X_s =  \left(\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{s}\right)Z$ is 
$\left(\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{s}\right)^2$ as your book claims, and not
$(t-s)$ as you calculated.

Comment: Thank you, seems like i had a number of mistakes in what i did. that made it clear